# reading a pdf version >= 1.5, how to handle Cross Reference Stream Dictionary

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to read the xref table of a pdf version >= 1.5.

the xref table is an object:

```
58 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 4/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<CB05990F613E2FCB6120F059A2BCA25B><E2ED9D17A60FB145B03010B70517FC30>]/Index[38 39]/Info 37 0 R/Length 96/Prev 67529/Root 39 0 R/Size 77/Type/XRef/W[1 2 1]>>stream
hÞbbd``b`:$AD`­Ì ‰Õ Vˆ8âXAÄ×HÈ$€t¨  – ÁwHp·‚ŒZ$ìÄb!&F†­ .#5‰ÿŒ>(more here but can't paste)
endstream
endobj
```

as you can see

- /FlatDecode
- /Index [38 39], that is **39** entries in the stream
- /W [1 2 1] that is each entry is 1 + 2 + 1 = 4 bytes long
- /Root 39 0 R that is root object is number 39

**BUT :**

the decompressed stream is 195 bytes long (**39** * 5 = 195). So the length of an entry is 4 or 5.

Here is the first inflated bytes

```
02 01 00 10 00 02 00 02 cd 00 02 00 01 51 00 02 00 01 70 00 02 00 05 7a 00 02
            ^^
```

if entry length is 4 then the root entry is a free object (see the ^^) !!

if the entry is 5: how to interpret the fields of one entry (reference is implicitly made to [PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf.html), chapter 3.4.7 table 3.16 ) ?

For object 38, the first of the stream: it seems, as it is of type 2, to be the 16 object of the stream object number 256, but there is no object 256 in my pdf file !!!

The question is: how shall I handle the 195 bytes ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A compressed xref table may have been compressed with one of the PNG filters. If the `/Predictor` value is set to '10' or greater ("a Predictor value greater than or equal to 10 merely indicates that a PNG predictor is in use; the specific predictor function used is explicitly encoded in the incoming data")<sup>1</sup>, PNG row filters are supplied inside the compressed data "as usual" (i.e., in the first byte of each 'row', where the 'row' is of the width in `/W`).

Width [1 2 1] *plus* Predictor byte:

```
02 01 00 10 00
02 00 02 cd 00
02 00 01 51 00
02 00 01 70 00
02 00 05 7a 00
02 .. .. .. ..
```

After applying the row filters ('2', or 'up', for all of these rows), you get this:

```
01 00 10 00
01 02 ed 00
01 03 3e 00
01 04 ae 00
01 09 28 00
.. .. .. ..
```

*Note:* calculated by hand; I might have made the odd mistake here and there. Note that the PNG 'up' filter is a *byte* filter, and the result of the "up" filter is truncated to 8 bits for each addition.

This leads to the following Type 1 XRef references ("type 1 entries define objects that are in use but are not compressed (corresponding to n entries in a cross-reference table)."):<sup>2</sup>

```
#38 type 1: offset 10h, generation 0
#39 type 1: offset 2EDh, generation 0
#40 type 1: offset 33Eh, generation 0
#41 type 1: offset 4AEh, generation 0
#42 type 1: offset 928h, generation 0
```

<sup>1</sup> See **LZW and Flate Predictor Functions** in [PDF Reference 1.7, 6th Ed](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), Section 3.3: Filters.

<sup>2</sup> As described in your Table 3.16 in PDF Ref 1.7.

Comment: It seems that the second row after the row filters should be 01 02 **dd** 00 (0xcd + 0x10 = 0xdd). I didn't edit the answer because (1) I want to be really sure about it and (2) the decoding of all the other rows below it depend on 0xed (and seem to be correct as they are), so that would be a major edit that could end up being worse and more confusing than the original answer /* PS.: Maybe changing 10 to 20 would be an easier fix? */